# Convert 01.04.2022 to dd/mm/yy format

Tags: c#, datetime, type-conversion, datetime-format

I have a need to convert two date values to similar type and compare them.

both of the values are in string data type.

I have tried to convert string to datetime object then use toString but it didn't work as
"01.04.2022" this format computer interprets as mm/dd/yyyy when converting but it should be considered it as dd/mm/yyyy.

Below is the code. Let me how I can achieve this scenario.

```
string firstDate="01.04.2022";//this format computer interpretes as mm/dd/yyyy, how can tell to consider this as a dd/mm/yyyy when converting 
string secondDate="01/April/2022";
// converting the string to datetime object 
DateTime date1 =DateTime.Parse(firstDate);   
DateTime date2 =DateTime.Parse(secondDate);   
    
// converting it to a normalize format to compare
string d1 = date1.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") ;//we need to get 01/April/2022 from this variable
```

Comment: Use `ParseExact`.

Comment: custom IFormatProvider is the best option to avoid all culture conflicts and uncertainties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opah friend you can use this form to convert:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(input,"yyyyMMdd HH:mm",null);
```

in your case it would be

```
DateTime.ParseExact("01.04.2022", "mm.dd.yyyy", null);
```

if you want I have an idea for your method of comparison:

```
public static class CompareDates
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dateTime1"></param>
    /// <param name="dateTime2"></param>
    /// <returns>True when squal</returns>
    /// <returns>false when different</returns>
    public static bool CompareDate(this DateTime dateTime1, DateTime dateTime2) => DateTime.Compare(dateTime1.Date, dateTime2.Date) == 0;
}
```